# File upload HTTP API, Should I check zero file size and MIME type both?

Tags: java, spring, file, file-upload, mime-types

In image upload API (Spring)

I validate file like this

```
// pseudocode

MultipartFile image
if image.contentType != "image/~"
then throw

if image.size == 0
then throw
```

Should I check size zero?

I already check MIME type

Is it possible to make image MIME file with zero size?

```
(I validate maximum size with properties file)

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of length need to check bytes

```
if (image.getBytes()<100)
then throw
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)

Comment: thanks for comment. I mean, if making zero size image file is impossible. then its unnecessary to check file size.